# Is there a any fingerprint-library or framework to use for iphone app developement?

Tags: iphone

I would like to know whether something like this can be easily achieved, any suggestions?

Comment: I do not think that is available for public use

Comment: The iPhone screen is not sensitive enough to read fingerprints.

Comment: What Kenny said.  I've seen some private API means of grabbing the size of a touch, but it still is registered as a single touch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possibility would be reading in fingerprints via the camera.  However if you focus on a finger, it's simply not sensitive enough to discern the separate lines that make up a fingerprint.

So, the only possibility would be dedicated hardware that could read fingerprints and talk to the phone.

Comment: Thx for all the comments on this issue, i've wondered myself about some apps doing this kind of job and wether it is something serious or not

maybe we will see apple doing some kind of interesting hardware changes in the future